# Mysql memory settings

Tags: mysql, memory-management

I have a question regarding mysql memory settings. I am currently experimenting on very large tables. When I run complicated queries on them, `mysql` runs out of memory.

What is the appropriate settings in mysql that will allow a larger size of data to be processed at a time? and How do I change it?

Any info?

Comment: Did you even try to look in the MySQL docs? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//option-files.html

Comment: How can we answer that. Depends on how large your large tables are, the load on the server, and how complicated your complicated queries are! RTFM time.

Comment: Also, what type of tables are you using MyISAM or InnoDB?  You configure memory usage for each differently.

Comment: @Ray : The tables are of type innodb.  I see that in my.ini file it mentions that "This is for a system with little memory (32M - 64M).  I also see other files like my-huge.ini, and my-large.ini for large systems with memory 1G-2G and 512MB respectively.  Can I make use of these? If so is it ok if I just copy paste the config parameters into my.ini file? I am using tables which have about 10 million rows and are upto 1GB in size.  Sorry for my naive questions.  I am quite new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to this then you have a lot of effort to get up to speed.  MySQL is not nearly as bad as tuning Oracle but it does require some work.  Sorry for the bad news.  I would recommend you get yourself a copy of High Performance MySQL and look at the section on MySQL profiling and particularly Chapter 6 on optimizing server settings.

Without details, as colleagues have pointed out,  it is hard to make any sort of recommendations.

Also you may take a look at the following Google Video (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UcQVeO1JxSM)  It is old but concepts are there.

Good luck

PS - also check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/option-files.html for help on option files (cnf)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will go through